# What is this "and" statement actually doing in the return?

Tags: python, object, boolean, return

I am trying to get a better understanding of the following python code and why the author has used the "AND" statement in the return.

```
def valid_password(self, password):
        PASS_RE = re.compile(r'^.{6,128}$')
        return password and PASS_RE.match(password)
```

further down the code...

```
if not self.valid_password(self.password):
    params['error_password'] = "Please enter a valid password."
```

I've tried inspecting the resulting object that gets handed back to the caller, however I still don't entirely understand how it works.

It seems like this returns the password back to the caller and a boolean of whether or not the password is valid, however I don't understand how the calling function can check the bool of an object? Is this something basic about Python that I've missed?

There is another example of a similar usage next to this one however it uses the "or" statement which to me is even more confusing:

```
def valid_email(self, email):
    EMAIL_RE  = re.compile(r'^[\S]+@[\S]+\.[\S]+$')
    return not email or EMAIL_RE.match(email)
```

Any advice on exactly what is going on here would be greatly appreciated. The code works and does what you would expect it to do, validates the input against a regular expression and returns True or False, however I would really like to understand what it was written like this and not simply returning the bool.

Comment: Hey, man, I've tried to explain in my answer the building blocks used for those expressions, basically, short-circuit evaluation and python truth values -- they are important concepts on any language. Please tell me if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Python, both `and` and `or` will return one of their operands. With `or`, Python checks the first operand and, if it is a "truthy" value (more on truthiness later), it returns the first value without checking the second (this is called Boolean shortcut evaluation, and it can be important). If the first is "falsey", then Python returns the second operand, no matter what it is:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 2 or 3
2
>>> 0 or 3
3
```

With "and", much the same thing happens: the first operand is checked first, and if it is "falsey", then Python never checks the second operand. If the first operand is "truthy", then Python returns the second operand, no matter what it is:

```
>>> 2 and 3
3
>>> 0 and 3
0
>>> 3 and 0
0
>>> 3 and []
[]
>>> 0 and []
0
```

Now let's talk about "truthiness" and "falsiness". Python uses the following rules for evaluating things in a Boolean context:

- The following values are "falsey": False, None, 0 (zero), [] (the empty list), () (the empty tuple), {} (the empty dict), an empty set, "" (the empty string)
- Everything else is "truthy"

So something like `password and PASS_RE.match(password)` is taking advantage of Python's short-circuit evaluation. If `password` is None, then the `and` operator will just return None and never evaluate the second half. Which is good, because `PASS_RE.match(None)` would have thrown an exception. Watch this:

```
>>> 3 or []
3
>>> [] or 3
3
>>> 0 or []
[]
>>> [] or 0
0
>>> 0 and []
0
>>> [] and 0
[]
```

See how the short-circuiting is working? Now watch this:

```
>>> value = "hello"
>>> print (value.upper())
HELLO
>>> print (value and value.upper())
HELLO
>>> value = None
>>> print (value.upper())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'upper'
>>> print (value and value.upper())
None
```

See how the short-circuiting feature of `and` helped us avoid a traceback? That's what's going on in this function.

Comment: In fact, exactly half of the other answers is correct. So this answer is *incorrect* in it's claim that most other answers are incorrect. And I still don't like the "truthy" and "falsy", because it implies that they are "kinda true" or "kinda false".

Comment: It certainly was "most" when I started writing this. :-) I think there were three answers at the time, and only one didn't say "this returns a bool".

Comment: Showing the dangers of writing such a thing when answers can be edited. :-)

Comment: I guess I'll edit mine to say "Several" other answers are incorrect. :-)

Comment: @LennartRegebro although "kinda true" and "kinda false" isn't too far from the, uh, truth, because "`x` is truthy" implies `bool(x) == True` but not necessarily `x == True`.

Comment: Well, now that the incorrect answers have either been downvoted into oblivion or have been edited to stop saying "this function returns a boolean", I no longer need to have a "don't trust the other answers" warning in mine. So I've edited it out.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. Short-Circuit Evaluation is exactly what I was looking for as an explanation.

It seems that this function will return the results of the regex match (whatever they may be) unless the submitted password is evaluated as false(ish) when the function is run. The password would evaluate as false(ish) if it was an empty string or other None type as in your list of potential false data types (eg: 0).

This really helps me understand what is going on. I guess a long form of this function might be:

return password if not password else return result regex match

Comment: I forgot that (), the empty tuple, is also a "falsy" value in Python. I've edited my answer to include the empty tuple in the list of "falsy" values.

Comment: ... and I just edited it again to clarify that the 0 in the list of "falsy" values is a zero, not a capital O. I don't think it's likely to cause confusion, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: I just learned that most people are spelling it "falsey", not "falsy", so I've edited my answer to reflect that spelling.

Answer (score 7):

The line in question verifies that the password is ['truthy'](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/truth.html) and that it matches a predefined password regular expression.

Here's how it breaks down:

- The function returns `password` if `password` is ['falsey'](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/truth.html).
- If the password is 'truthy', but the password does not match the password regex, the function returns `None`.
- If there is a 'truthy' password, and it matches the regex, the [match object is returned](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match).

The `and` operator is a 'short-circuit' operator; If the first value is 'truthy', it returns the second value. Otherwise, it return the first value.

You can check out [this page](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/truth.html) to see what types of things are 'truthy' in python.

Comment: "truthy" and "falsey"... ugh... how about "tests as True" and "tests as False"?

Comment: @LennartRegebro it's because they are not really the `True` boolean value, they just happen to evaluate to True if used in a boolean context. Check out my answer for examples of boolean expressions using strings.

Comment: 'truthy' and 'falsey' are how these things are talked about, and is also descriptive. 'foo' is truthy, but 'foo' != True.  '' is falsey but '' != False.

Comment: I've never heard that before, and I already hate it. It's sounds like "Not false but almost" which is False. :-) This isn't fuzzy logic.

Comment: In your 3rd point, if the first value is -truthy-, then it returns the second value.

Comment: Thanks for the replies... this has really helped me understand short-circuit evaluation, something I had not encountered before.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to know that:

1. Empty strings in Python evaluates to `False` ([also `None`, empty lists, and other *"zero"* types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)).
2. Boolean expressions are subject to an optimization called [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Therefore,

```
a = '1'
print('' and a)
```

... prints the empty string because as it is False, the expression can never be `True` and the second part (the `a`) is never even evaluated.

And

```
a = '1'
print('' or a)
```

prints `'1'`, because the empty string is False, the second part has to be evaluated to give the result of the expression.